Sources/opinions on punctuation in ketubah
I'm designing a ketubah with a request for nekudot, which is fine (I have sources), but also punctuation. So I'm curious if anyone has learned anything on that?

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Which vowels would you use anyway? There are various opinions on how to properly mark all the words.

Opinion of Rav Elyashiv: Sefer Ashrei HaIsh Vol. Even HaEzer 1(9,37):

לא יערכו כתובה מנוקדת כי הוא שינוי במסורת כתיבת הכתובה

My rough Translation:

Ktuba should not be written with punctuations because it is a change in the custom of writing ketuba.

I saw a few other books who mentioned one doesn't need to be careful with it.
And this is an answer from Beit horaah din who says one need not be careful with it.
